# Preencher campos de um array multidimensional com null

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho este **[código](http://pastebin.com/PaVh3cMm)** que me retorna este **[array](http://axitech.com.br/vista/dois.php)** e se reparar, poderá ver que tem campos vazios. O que eu posso incrementar nesse código para que aonde o índice esteja vazio receba o valor **null**?

Assim funciona, mas para meu **array** multidimensional não funcionou.

```
$array = array('A'=>1,'B'=>'','C'=>3,'D'=>'','E'=>5,'F'=>6);

array_walk($array , function( &$value , $field){
    if(! $value) $value = '0';
});

print_r($array);
```

---

<sup>**Resolvi** minha aplicação usando a solução do @Jader, o `array_walk_recursive`, talvez tenha aplicado a mesma solução de @Papa Charlie mas acabei compreendendo melhor pela resposta de @Jader. A solução apresentada me permitiu com a função acessar vários níveis da **array** que era multidimensional.</sup>

Comment: Um indice vazio é null.

Comment: Editei o titulo para ficar mais sugestivo, ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para obter recursividade em "infinitos" níveis, você precisa criar uma função, e essa função deve verificar se o valor é um array e se aplicar ela mesma, dessa forma:

*Obs: Mantenho essa forma na resposta, pois ela pode ser útil para outras pessoas, caso o objetivo da função seja mais complexo e não possa ser feito com o `array_walk_recursive`.*

```
function null_array($array) {
    foreach($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) $value = null_array($value);
        else if (empty($value)) $value = '0';
    }
    return $array;
}

$array = array('A'=>1,'B'=>'','C'=>3,'D'=>'','E'=>5,'F'=>6, 'G' => array('A'=>1,'B'=>'','C'=>3,'D'=>'','E'=>5));

$array = null_array($array);

print_r($array);

// retorno
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 0
    [C] => 3
    [D] => 0
    [E] => 5
    [F] => 6
    [G] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1
            [B] => 0
            [C] => 3
            [D] => 0
            [E] => 5
        )

)
```

Ou simplesmente mudar a função `array_walk` para [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php), obtém o mesmo efeito:

```
array_walk_recursive($array , function( &$value , $field){
    if(! $value) $value = '0';
});
```

Comment: O seu exemplo passa o campo filter como array, coloque uma regra para array vazio retornar zero, assim só terá string no resultado e pode jogar no DB direto como ele pretende.

Answer (score 4):

> [**array_walk**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk.php) — Aplica uma determinada funcão em cada elemento de um array

```
array_walk( $arrays , function( &$array ){
    foreach( $array as $item => &$value ) {
        if( ! $value ) $value = '0';
    }
});

print_r( $arrays );
```

Isso vai substituir todo valor `null` por zero

output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
            [Data cadastro] => 2012-03-16
            [Endereco] => CASEMIRO DE ABREU
            [Data Ativacao] => 2014-02-10
    [1] => Array
            [Data cadastro] => 2012-03-16
            [Endereco] => CASEMIRO DE ABREU
            [Data Ativacao] => 0
)
```

Comment: Eu tenho um **array** dentro de outro **array** e isso fez com que o código que me passou não funcionasse. Além dessa situação de **array** multidimensional, ainda tem isso: `$res = $client->get($array)` que está provavelmente atrapalhando a execução do código que me passou.

Comment: vou ajustar o codigo

Comment: Lembrando que eu preciso aplicar o código nesta estrutura que é a estrutura do web-service: http://pastebin.com/PaVh3cMm

Comment: resposta atualizada

Comment: @PapaCharlie Assim você não tem recursividade, apenas o primeiro nível vai ser processado, e ainda gera erro se o valor não for array... Veja [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Comment: sim sim, esta incompleta

Comment: http://axitech.com.br/vista/alimentador.xml ... @PapaCharlie resolvi um bocado dos meus problemas, removi o `CDATA` e adicionei **0** aos campos vazios para não gerar erro na automatização do `XML` que realmente tinha erro por causa dos campos vazios.

Comment: Deu um erro `error on line 594`

Comment: Eu tentando e quando aumento muito o número de registros, dá erro. Até 50 registros ele vai bem, depois não funciona mais. Mas porque ele vai certinho até um certo ponto e depois planta?

Comment: agora aparenta estar direitinho

Answer (score 2):

Basta iterar nos elementos e mudar o valor deles caso eles sejam nulos:

```
foreach($res as $key => $val) {
  if (empty($res[$key])) $res[$key] = null;
}
```

Comment: Na verdade não posso retirá-los, tenho realmente que inserir **null** nos campos vazios porque este arquivo fará parte de um **dump** mais tarde, então preciso de todos os campos que serão colunas no banco de dados estejam intactos.

Comment: Desculpa cara, interpretei errado. Resposta corrigida! =)

Comment: Mas ainda sim vc poderia melhorar sua pergunta, com exemplos menores para o código de entrada e saída.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, acho que é isto que está querendo:

```
$minhaArray = array('A'=>1,'B'=>'','C'=>3,'D'=>'','E'=>5,'F'=>6);

foreach($minhaArray as $elemento) {
    if(strlen($elemento) == 0) {
        unset($elemento); // Aqui faz o elemento vazio ficar NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: O modelo do meu código é um `array` dentro de outro `array`. Vendo o código consegue dar uma solução melhor para meu caso? E você @Peoplee?

Comment: vou verificar aqui